# Why doesn't Scalavista see the dependencies set in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, sbt, dependency-management

Scalavista, or Scala Syntax (official) - these are the Scala extensions I have.

I have in build.sbt e.g.

```
  , "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % "latest.integration"
```

and when I write

```
import org.scalatra.json._
```

then it marks it as an error and says `object scalatra is not a member of package org`. And it's just one example, my code is full of red waves. And that's only in vscode; when I run the program from sbt, it compiles and works OK.

Shouldn't it be aware of the dependencies?

Comment: ~Which VSCode extension are you using for SBT integration? Metals?~ Oh, that's what you meant with scala extensions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the [sbt-scalavista](https://github.com/buntec/sbt-scalavista) SBT plugin in order to let it generate the scalavista config for your project.